# Existing process in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Is it possible or does it make sense to exit a node process in a function as I have here:

```
export function extractOptions(options){
  for (let option of options) {
    if(!option || option.length < 1){
      logMissing(option[0][0])
      process.exit(1)
      return []
    }
  }

  return options
}
```

My test doesn't get back a [] if the if statement finds that there is no option or option length is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you exit the process, your processing stops immediately.  You won't return a return value, b/c there's nothing running to return it to.

If you exit the process with a non-false/null value (like process.exit(1)) you not only exit immediately, but the OS reports that an error has happened.

Comment: so I should handle existing the process out of the scope of this function then, the caller should exit if this function produces undesired results